# polymer core-tooltip: transitioning visiblitity

Tags: css, css-transitions, polymer

I want to delay the display of tooltips on hover. I seem to be able to delay them disappearing but I want the exact opposite. I want them to take 1s before they display on hover but disappear immediately when no longer on hover

The following has the exact opposite effect to what I want

```
core-tooltip /deep/ * {
  transition: visibility 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating delayed CSS3 transitions for an element requires a [transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) property.

[Live demo](https://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/preview.html#c47551f32ef8cdeba37d) demonstrates a tooltip shown after a one second delay. Source below in case the link isn't saved.

```
<link rel="import" href="../core-tooltip/core-tooltip.html">

<polymer-element name="my-element">

  <template>
    <style>    
      #span {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 280px;
        height: 130px;
      }
      #core_tooltip {
        width: 90px;
        height: 30px;
        left: 660px;
        top: 290px;
        position: absolute;
      }
      core-tooltip.special:hover::shadow .core-tooltip, core-tooltip.special:focus::shadow .core-tooltip {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
        transition-delay: 1s;
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
      }
    </style>
    <core-tooltip label="I'm a tooltip" id="core_tooltip" class="special">
      <span id="span">Delay for a second</span>
    </core-tooltip>
  </template>

  <script>

    Polymer({

    });

  </script>

</polymer-element>
```